# How to convert a vector to a cell array in matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I have two pieces of codes as the following:

```
nodes = randsample ( n_nodes, round(j*n_nodes) )-1;      
nodes_seqs = arrayfun (@transfer, nodes, 'UniformOutput', false );

nodes = num2str(nodes);

nodes = cellstr(nodes);
file_n = strcat('fasta','_','myfilename' );  % file  name

fastawrite(strcat( file_n, '.fas' ), nodes, nodes_seqs);
```

The other one is:

```
nodes = 0 : n_nodes-1;

nodes_seqs = arrayfun (@transfer, nodes, 'UniformOutput', false );

nodes = num2str(nodes);

nodes = cellstr(nodes);
file_n = strcat('myfilename' );  % file  name

fastawrite(strcat( file_n, '.fas' ), nodes, nodes_seqs);
```

The first one runs as expected. However, I got an error for the second one. After checking the variables, I got that in the second one, the nodes is a 1 by 1 cell array. I was confused. How comes it works on the first one, not the second one? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I finally figure out the reason.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case since nodes is a cell array you need to use

`nodes = cell2mat(nodes)` instead of `num2str` as your data is of type cell at that point not num.

Here is a link to the function [documentation on Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)

Other options are the functions `cell2struct()` or `cell2table()`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The main reason here is: in the first piece, the randsample returns a column vector, while in the second piece, the nodes is initialized to be a row vector. After adding a transpose, it works.